# App's album cover - iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, wallpaper, albumart

I am making an app that plays audio... with each sound piece playing I want to be able to change the "album cover" on the wallpaper of the phone... For example when you play a song on the iPod app it changes your lock screen wallpaper to an album cover photo... so how do I do this for my app, when audio is playing within my app changing the lock screen wallpaper temporarily to the album cover? Any ideas? I was thinking of playing an audio file that actually has a picture compressed into it as the wallpaper image like some iTunes songs but I know not all do that and they still get images.. hmmm Anyways I know it's possible because I own some apps that do that... Thanks if anyone can come up with anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS5+ you can use the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` Class to achieve what you want. On version prior iOS5 this is not possible with public APIs.

More Info can be found in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention the property name ^^